# Web service - method naming?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, soap, webservice-client

I know naming a webservice method is probably a personal preference, however I'm interested to know what you guys would name it, and why?

## 1:

```
AccountCreate
AccountDelete
AccountList
AccountUpdate
```

or

## 2:

```
CreateAccount
DeleteAccount
ListAccount
UpdateAccount
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're obviously building SOAP based Web Services. When choosing names for those, I tend to go with the most natural English representation. In your case, that is your second set of options.

For me, it makes things clearer and easier for people consuming my services if I name them as close to plain English as possible. For instance if people are trying to create something, but they're not really sure what, they can scan through the documentation of the Create operations and find the closest match for what they need.

It's also consistent with how I name the rest of my methods (assuming we're not talking about RESTful URLs).

Answer (score 3):

Number 2, because I allways use [Verb][object] in methods where possible.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
/Account/Create
        /Delete
        /List
        /Update
```